# how to convert HTML website to wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

By using a default theme in WordPress example:twenty thirteen,by editing in it and applying my CSS I got my header and footer but I'm facing a lot of problem in making pages because it takes the default CSS of the theme I'm applying my css but not getting the same page like my HTML
page

Comment: If you don't know how to convert an html website to wordpress you could use http://wpsiteconvertor.com/, it's an easy tool that lets you convert your website design to a wordpress theme really quickly without any wordpress coding knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is a content management system. You don't "convert" the code you build the site with that system. You could read all about it here: https://wordpress.org/

Comment: but a site made in pure html.can me made in wordpress.this is my task and i want to complete it very fast.so plss help

Comment: My advice is to resurch how it works first. Ask a friend or read some documentation. You can't build a site in wordpress if you don't know what it can do.

Comment: @user3313526 My advice would be to hire someone who knows what they're doing. With no prior knowledge of WordPress the quality of the conversion will be extremely poor at best.

Comment: what it can do???means....its my company task given to me..they have given me a HTML full code including its CSS and everything is made and running..i only want to make it in wordpress

Comment: Google 'html to wordpress tutorial'. and follow any of tutorial

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is actually very easy if you know what you are doing.

I could type out all the details, but that would take a super long time. But since there is already a video about this I will just post that here. Hope this will help you.

http://marketingonlineworkshop.com/coding-a-wordpress-theme-demonstrated-for-you-module-1/